# Intellij IDEA 14 crashed frequently on OS X El Capitan

Tags: intellij-idea, crash, osx-elcapitan

I upgraded my system from OSX Yosemite into El Capitan the day before yesterday, then the ***IntelliJ IDEA 14 *** is CRASHed 5 times during 3 hours today. Does anyone meet this question? I have not got this situation before this upgrade

Comment: I'm also running IntelliJ 14 on El Cap and encountered no crashes whatsoever ... which JRE are you using (you can see it in IntelliJ IDEA/About IntelliJ IDEA dialog)? I'm using Apple JRE 1.6 as runtime for IntelliJ which I had to redownload after the upgrade from Yosemite ...

Comment: @BohuslavBurghardt I'm using jdk7, got from oracle official site, as the runtime for IDEA, and it's ok before this upgrade.  It makes me confused to crash frequently

Comment: I am also experiencing instant crashes after upgrading to El Capitan. I remember it forced me to install another version of java saying something about it being deprecated soon. My current JRE version is1.6.0_65 and IntelliJ version is 14.1.5 -- I'd like to note that it seems to crash at some point when it is trying to do code completion. I've noticed that when the program gets focus there is a bit of latency before you can interact with the program now.

Comment: @Nuthman I remember it also forced me to install a JRE patch when it was starting several days ago. I find that the IDEA JRE is 1.6.0_65, but my JAVA_HOME is pointed to 1.8, it may be the question? I try to change it into 1.8

Comment: @Frank Yeah I think you may be right - after I commented I went and installed JDK 8 and changed:  <key>JVMVersion</key><string>1.6*</string> to 1.8*  in Applications/IntelliJ Idea 14/Contents/Info.plist --- So far I've had no more crashes. Fingers crossed!

Comment: @Nuthman me too, it has worked very well after I changed the JVMVersion from 1.6 to 1.8. Thanks for your experience.

Comment: I have the same behaviour. Also multiple crashes a day. I looked a bit on the internet and found this on the jetBrains developer community: `Note that IntelliJ IDEA doesn't run well on JDK 1.6 on Mac because of multiple Apple bugs.` Changed it to 1.7 and hope my intelliJ will run more stable from now on. Here is explained how you can change the JVMVersion property: https://devnet.jetbrains.com/docs/DOC-197

Comment: I use 1.8.40 but IntelliJ still crashes once in aa while, like very 2 days or so. It leaves "ghost" java processes behinf (Tomcat, Spring boot) that I have to manually kill, less the HTTP port (8080) is not released. Since it's not so frequent, I can deal with it.

Comment: @PierreHenry, it worked well after I changed the JDK from 1.6 to 1.8. I'm working with the IntelliJ IDEA 15, and never meet this problem again.

Answer (score 5):

I did not have this behaviour since 3 days in new version of Intellij 15 https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/ intellij 15.0.3 in El capitan os-x 10.11.3

This seems to bug in both intellij 14 and 15, which  can be seen here https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-147081, I received a email from the support stating these exact words

"Mentioned [build](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/26496208/ideaIU-144.1368-custom-jdk-bundled.dmg) includes potential fix for the problem. If you are concern about stability, you can wait for released 15.1.X version from http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/index.html"

Increase the votes and may be they will fix it soon :)